# Problem loading combobox from dataset VB.NET MvvM

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, data-binding, dataset

Attempting to load up a combobox from database using a dataset; items do not show up in the combobox. Attempting to do this without writing any codebehind.

The Model:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class ChainModel
    Public Property ChainId As String
    Public Property ChainType As String

    Public Sub New(chainId As String, chainType As String)
        Me.ChainId = chainId
        Me.ChainType = chainType
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Dataset population:

```
Public Class DBCollection
    Public Shared dsChains As DataSet

    Public Shared Sub FillDataSet()
        Try
            dsChains = New DataSet()
            Dim adpt As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter With {
                .SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Chain ORDER BY Name, Manufacturer;", DbConn)
            }
            adpt.Fill(dsChains, Tbl)
            adpt.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception
            MsgBox("Unable to populate dataset! " & vbCrLf & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The ViewModel:

```
Public Class TTStraightViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements 
    INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Dim _chainTypes As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel) = New ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel)()

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Property ChainTypes As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel)
        Get
            If _chainTypes.Count = 0 Then DBLoadChains()
            Return _chainTypes
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel))
            _chainTypes = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ChainTypes")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub DBLoadChains()
        For Each row As DataRow In DBCollection.dsChains.Tables("ChainTable").Rows
            Dim display As String = row("Name").ToString
            Dim value As String = row("id").ToString
            If display = String.Empty Then display = value
            _chainTypes.Add(New ChainModel(value, display))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TtStraightView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace: LayoutTools" ResizeMode="NoResize" Width="Auto" 
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:LayoutTools.My" 
Title="Table Top Conveyor Straight" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="Auto">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TTStraightViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <p:MySettings x:Key="MySettings" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Margin="0,3,0,3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="230" SelectedValuePath="ChainId" DisplayMemberPath="ChainType" ItemsSource="{Binding ChainTypes}"/>    
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

DBCollection.FillDataSet() is called during program startup.

Been grappling with this for days, research, previous code and all, and still can't figure out why the combobox doesn't show any items when I run the code. Any ideas?

Comment: `Catch ex As Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception` Why AutoCAD in a simple OleDb ADO.net operation. I wouldn't think you would want to show a message box is a data access class. Let it bubble up to the user interface is all you are going to do is show a message box.

Comment: What is Tbl? I assume it is the name of the datatable but I don't see where it is defined.

Comment: You're right, 'Tbl' is defined elsewhere as a globally-accessible property --> Tbl As String = "Chain"

Comment: Just removed the try-catch block and tested the code again, hoping that some sort of error would popup - bot no, nothing. And the combobox still has no items shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this sticky situation of mine, and, for anyone working in VB.NET who might be remotely interested in how to populate a combobox with database data the MvvM way (without any codebehind), here's how I accomplished it.

1) Create a class to emulate the properties of the database table as required:

```
Public Class ChainModel
    Public Property ChainId As Integer

    Public Property ChainType As String

    Public Sub New(chainId As Integer, chainType As String)
        Me.ChainId = chainId
        Me.ChainType = chainType
    End Sub
End Class
```

2) Create a database class to populate the dataset to be used (be sure to have your database connection set up before this step):

```
Public Class DBCollection
    Public Shared dsChains As DataSet
    Public Shared Sub FillDataSet()
        dsChains = New DataSet()
        Dim adpt As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter With {
            .SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT id,Name FROM Chain ORDER BY Name, Manufacturer;", Cat.DbConn)
            }
        adpt.Fill(dsChains,"Chain")
        adpt.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

3) Set up the MvvM model class such that the dataset is populated in constructor, and the observable collection property of the model is populated directly from dataset:

```
Public Class TTStraightModel
    Dim _chainType As String = My.Settings.TTStraightChainType
    Dim _chainTypeList As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel)

    Public Sub New()
        DBCollection.FillDataSet()
    End Sub

    Public Property ChainType As String
        Get
            Return _chainType
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _chainType = value
            My.Settings.TTStraightChainType = _chainType
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ChainTypeList As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel)
        Get
            _chainTypeList = New ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel)()
            For Each row As DataRow In DBCollection.dsChains.Tables("Chain").Rows
                Dim display As String = row("Name").ToString
                Dim value As String = row("id").ToString
                If display = String.Empty Then display = value
                _chainTypeList.Add(New ChainModel(value, display))
            Next
            Return _chainTypeList
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel))
            _chainTypeList = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

4) Set up the MvvM view-model such that it reads the model's observable collection property into an observable collection property of its own:

```
Public Class TTStraightViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements 
INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    ReadOnly _ttStraightModel As New TTStraightModel()

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property ChainType As String
        Get
            Return _ttStraightModel.ChainType
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ttStraightModel.ChainType = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ChainType")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ChainTypeList As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel)
        Get
            Return _ttStraightModel.ChainTypeList
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ChainModel))
            _ttStraightModel.ChainTypeList = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ChainTypeList")
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

5) Finally, set up the MvvM XAML view such that the combobox binds directly to the view model's exposed property (after having first set up the view model as data context for the view):

```
<Window x:Class="TtStraightView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CatScriptLayoutTools" ResizeMode="NoResize" Width="Auto" 
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:CatScriptLayoutTools.My" 
    Title="Table Top Conveyor Straight" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="Auto">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TTStraightViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <p:MySettings x:Key="MySettings" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Margin="0,3,0,3" Width="230" SelectedValuePath="ChainId" DisplayMemberPath="ChainType" ItemsSource="{Binding ChainTypeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ChainType}"/>    
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The SelectedValuePath="ChainId" DisplayMemberPath="ChainType" ensure that the proper id/value combination is bound to the combobox.